# blank images when logging in one account through vscode ssh-remote

Tags: vscode-remote

If I log in one user account through vscode ssh-remote and open any image, it can be loaded but become blank\

[image: 1]

However, if I log in another account and open any image at the same time, both the images can be loaded and viewed correctly.\

[image: 2]

No special extension, no special ssh configuration。

hope to vdiew images through ssh normally

Answer (score 0):

finished! remove any characters beside English in the path of .ssh files